# Issue with sending a POST request from Rails to Local Webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I am trying to send a POST request to a Web Service. The curl command I am using is:

```
curl --silent --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data 
'{"mwtype":"serviceproviders/GetReport","url":"<an url>"}' http://localhost:8080/service/serviceproviders/v1
```

and it was able to successfully give a response. In my Rail Code, I am doing this:

```
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:8080/service/serviceproviders/v1")
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'mwtype' => 'serviceproviders/GetReport', 'url' => '<some url>')
    if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess) 
      puts res.body
    else
      puts "Something went wrong"
      puts res
    end
```

but I am getting a `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your cURL request you're sending JSON. But `Net::HTTP.post_form` is used to send form data pairs for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Instead you want to use the normal `post` method:

```ruby
data = { 'mwtype' => 'serviceproviders/GetReport', 'url' => '<some url>' }
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:8080/service/serviceproviders/v1")
res = Net::HTTP.post(uri, data.to_json, "Content-Type" => "application/json")

if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess) 
  puts res.body
else
  puts "Something went wrong"
  puts res
end
```